# basename and convert in bash script error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, type-conversion, filenames

I am a beginner in bash script programming. I'm trying to make a function to convert a large number of photo files without changing the name. I have read several topics about using basename or {s%.*} to remove the type, but without succeeding in applying it.

thanks in advance for your help

```
#!/bin/bash

FOLDER=~/Bureau/data/jpg 
ERROR="$FOLDER/error.txt"
CURRENT=$PWD

if ! [[ -d "$FOLDER" ]]|| ! [[ -e $ERROR ]]
then
    mkdir -p $FOLDER
    touch $ERROR
else
    rm -f "$FOLDER/*"
    touch $ERROR
fi

for img in "$CURRENT/*.tif"; do
    filename=$(basename -- "$img")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    convert $img "$FOLDER/$filename.jpg" 2> $ERROR
done
```

Error images[image]

[image]

Comment: you placed your glob between quotes. This does not expand the glob but just keeps it as an astrisk. Do the following replacement `"$CURRENT/*.tif"` -> `"$CURRENT"/*.tif`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="~/Bureau/data/jpg"
rm -fr "$dir/"                   # -f doesn't fail if it didn't exist
mkdir -p "$dir"                  # -p doesn't fail if it *did* exist
for img in "$PWD"/*.tif; do 
  stub="${img%.tif}"             # simple strip the end 
  convert "$img" "$dir/$stub.jpg" 2> "$stub.err # err log per file
done # 2> "$dir/err.log" # if you don't want an error per, use this instead
```

You have a lot of cases of globs in quotes, which doesn't work.
Use `"$PWD"/*.tif` instead of `"$PWD/*.tif"`.
Also, `2>` inside the loop overwrites. Either use `2>>`, or `2>` *outside* the loop.

Comment: It's work ! Thanks. I just changed the pwd and the error file :)

Comment: Excellent. Accept the solution?